# Can you compare regression models using RMSE when samples have different proportions of zeros?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, zero-inflation, rms

I am using the `ranger` package (which implements random forests) in R to build regression models of tree species' basal area, a continuous measure of abundance and size.  Predictors are climate variables.  From a very large dataset I am selecting a sample of $400,000$ points for training for each species.  I then test prediction with $100,000$ other points  For most species, zeros (indicating absence) are much more common than positive values and the data are left-skewed.

I want to test how the proportion of zeros included in the sample affects predictive performance of the model. I'm using a range of proportions of zero from $0$ to $0.5$.

I have read in many answers that RMSE can't be used to compare models if the scale of the dependent variable is different. In this case, the scale is the same, but I'm concerned that the differing proportion of $0$s may affect RMSE independently of model performance.  Should that be a concern?  I could always use $R^2$ instead.

Comment: I suspect you have [zero-inflated data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-inflation?tab=Votes), i.e., your data could be represented by two coupled models: first you model presence/absence, then you model abundance for presence.

Comment: That's an interesting idea @Roland. I guess I would train a classification pres/abs model with a 50% presence sample, then train the regression model with only with the half of samples actually present.  In predicting, I would first predict pres/abs, then predict basal area with the regression model on the subset predicted to be present.  Sound right?

Comment: Only problem is, regression predictions with no 0s are the worst, and improve the more 0s you add.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you have a dataset which includes exclusively positive values (e.g. proportions like yours), then you will likely need to fit your model in a way that *only* includes positive values. Much has been said about how regressions like Poisson, negative binomial, etc. achieve this. After fitting the model, you may still believe there are just too many zeroes, and may want to check, as noted by your question below:

> I want to test how the proportion of zeros included in the sample affects predictive performance of the model. I'm using a range of proportions of zero from 0 to 0.5.

The most common test that I've seen for this is to fit your model and then compare the predicted zero values against the observed zero values. If the observed zero values are much higher, then your model is underfitting and is consequently zero-inflated. This often happens when there is some data generating process that in some part explains differences in zero counts and positive counts, which you hint at below:

> For most species, zeros (indicating absence) are much more common than positive values and the data are left-skewed.

I think you mean right-skewed by the way...its impossible for proportional data to be left-skewed unless you've done something weird like inverse coding. In any case, as Roland suggested, you can use something like a zero-inflated regression to overcome this issue. The theoretical justification for using this method is that you treat your dependent variable as a mixture distribution composed of two zero-generating processes: one which is the "zero" model and the other which is the Poisson "count" model (where some of the counts are still zero). Regarding model metrics:

> I have read in many answers that RMSE can't be used to compare models if the scale of the dependent variable is different. In this case, the scale is the same, but I'm concerned that the differing proportion of 0s may affect RMSE independently of model performance. Should that be a concern? I could always use $R^2$ instead.

You ought to use both as a guiding metric for how your model is behaving, as they say different things. For learning more about zero-inflated regression (and because you are using R), [this link](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/zip/#:%7E:text=Zero%2Dinflated%20Poisson%20regression%20is,zeros%20can%20be%20modeled%20independently.) shows how to run this. [Hilbe's book on negative binomial models](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/negative-binomial-regression/12D6281A46B9A980DC6021080C9419E7) has a lot more information on these models.